# grub-install: error: embedding is not possible

Tags: grub2

> grub-install: warning: your core.img is unusually large.  It won't fit
>   in the embedding area. grub-install: error: embedding is not possible,
>   but this is required for RAID and LVM install.

**Question:** Can we use GRUB or Lilo to boot a fresh Ubuntu? Or we can only use grub2 for booting it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a fresh installation, or an upgrade without repartitioning?  I had this problem a while ago when upgrading an old disk.  The old partition tables only reserved 32kB at the start of the disk, and that wasn't enough room for grub2 to install it's images.

I was running LVM+RAID1, so I was able to break the mirror, repartition with 1MB reserved at the front of the disk, shrink the filesystems, remirror, and repeat on the other disk.